# Not mounting after restart?

Tags: mount, fstab

I am mounting a drive via SSH, and then editing the fstab to reflect the changes, however after I reboot, the drive doesnt mount?

I dont understand what I'm doing wrong?

This is my fstab and its /md0 that isnt mounting after reboot, am I missing something?

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md4    /   ext3    errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0  0   1
/dev/md0    /BACKUP ext3    defaults    0   1
/dev/md1    /boot   ext3    errors=remount-ro   0   1
/dev/md2    /var/tmp    ext3    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0    1   2
/dev/sda3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sdb3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
sysfs       /sys    sysfs   defaults        0   0
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults    0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  defaults    0   0
```

Comment: Is the network started and ssh running by the time the system goes through fstab?

Comment: hi, im not sure if ssh running by that time, i wouldnt have thought so?

Comment: `/dev/mdX` is supposed to be a RAID device - is it properly created during boot? It usually requires you to have at least `mdadm --auto-detect` run before you can use it (and supposing you have created the RAD with a superblock that can be detected).

Comment: The output of `grep --after-context=3 -- md0 /proc/mdstat`, please.

Comment: You have not even specified an OS - different OS' have different fstab formats.  Please help us avoid guessing, and timestamp your questions by specifying your OS distribution and version.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the cause is not the `fstab` configuration itself, the problem could lay somewhere else.

By simply adding a `swap` entry into your `/etc/fstab` file it does not magically activate the swap partition. Usually this is done by a `swapon` call, which can be made either manually or `programatically`:

- Manually: simply run `swapon -a` in your terminal which will try to turn on all swap partition declared within your `fstab` file.
- Programatically: hopefully your distro comes with a `/etc/init.d/swap` daemon/service which does just that.

I had a situation when for some reasons I wanted to deactivate the swap (by `swapoff` and also prevent re-mounting automatically after each reboot by removing the `init` script service). However, after some time I changed my mind and I set back the swap except that I forgot to re-add the `swap` init script service (eg. /etc/init.d/swap).

So I fixed it by (1) configuring the `fstab` and (2) by adding the `swap` init script service.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to a disk migration issue in Digital Ocean. Which caused the disk UUID to change. I found out that the disk configuration can be in multiple places.

The first one was in `/etc/fstab` file (your approach), second one was defined in `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-volume_*.mount` file → This point out to wrong UUID and systemd tried to mount it despite configuration set in `fstab`

**Solution:**

1. Remove `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-volume_*.mount` file
2. Remount disk (mount command + adjust `fstab`)
3. Restart system → everything should work well.

Source: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/volumes/how-to/detach/